WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine -NPM
I am trying to do a npm install on my project but it gives below error
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'module_name_xyz',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '=18.x.x', npm: '=9.x.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.15.1', npm: '8.11.0' }

I tried installing the nvm version that this module needs , but after installing that newer version, the other dependent modules are breaking.
I also tried doing this in package.json
  "engines": {
"node": ">=16.x.x",
"npm": ">=8.x.x"

Still same issue, what can be done here
